flutter stateless widget returned previous and current as same values
We are using Bloc Pattern with Stateless TextFormField. TextFormField is having onChanged event, we are passing EmailAddressChanged to onChanged event.
EmailAddressChanged will emit state whether email address is already exists in database or not by checking flag isAccountExists and emitting state, so it will display message as "Email Address already exists. Please Login."
Our real issue is
whenever we type anything in email address textfield , previous state and current state did not got changed and hence it wont rebuild the UI resulted in not showing message of "Email Address Already exists"
Please find attached image. for prev. current state logged in console. Email address changed from suresh.pal@gmail.co to suresh.pal@gmail.com . But state is showing same values.

This is our build Widget method.
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return BlocBuilder<AccountBloc, AccountState>(
  buildWhen: (previous, current) =>
      previous.user?.emailAddress != current.user?.emailAddress,
  builder: (context, state) {
    // textController.text=state.user!.emailAddress.toString() ;
    var appContext = OnAppContext.of(context);
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 0),
      child: (
        null,
        'Email address*',
        textController,
        (emailAddress) => {
           context
               .read<AccountBloc>()
               .add(EmailAddressChanged(emailAddress: emailAddress))
        },
        (emailAddress) {
          bool emailValidate = RegExp(
                  // ignore: unnecessary_string_escapes
                  "^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,253}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,253}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*")
              .hasMatch(emailAddress!);
          if (emailAddress.isEmpty) {
            return 'Enter an email address';
          } else if (!emailValidate) {
            return 'Enter a valid email address';
          }
          return null;
        },
        context,
        isPasswordField: false,
        error: state.user?.isAccountExists == true
            ? AppContext.of(context).getTextButton(
                'This email is already registered. Log in',
                fontColor: appContext.incorrectColor,
                () => {Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/login')},
                true,
                context)
            : null,
        bottom: 20,
      ),
    );
  },
);

}
}
Definition of internal method
Widget getFormTextFieldWidgetRedOutline(
      String? data,
      String label,
      TextEditingController? controller,
      Function(String)? onChanged,
      String? Function(String?)? onValidation,
      BuildContext context,
      {bool isPasswordField = false,
      double bottom = 20,
      textColor,
      error,onFocus}) {
    return Column(children: [
      Align(
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          child: Text(
            label,
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyLarge?.copyWith(
                color: textColor ?? screenTitleColor,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
            softWrap: true,
          )),
      SizedBox(
          child: FocusScope(
            child: Focus(
              onFocusChange:onFocus,
                  //(focus) => print("focus: $focus"),
              child: TextFormField(
                onTapOutside: (PointerDownEvent event) {
                  FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
                },
                autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                controller: controller,
                onChanged: onChanged,
                obscureText: isPasswordField,
                validator: onValidation,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  // prefixIcon is used to add a small space before the text field
                  // can't use contentPadding becuase that controls both input and errror text padding
                  prefixIcon: Container(width: 0),
                  prefixIconConstraints: BoxConstraints.tight(const Size(10, 44)),
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                  error: error,
                  enabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.grey)),
                  border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
                  errorStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: incorrectColor),
                  fillColor: Colors.white,
                  filled: true,
                  floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.never,
                ),
              ),

            ),
          )),
      Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: bottom))
    ]);
  }

Bloc Pattern Event
FutureOr<void> _onEmailAddressChanged(
      EmailAddressChanged event, Emitter<AccountState> emit) async {
    
    ApiResponse<AccountExistsResponse>? response;
    state.user?.emailAddress = event.emailAddress;
    print(state.user!.emailAddress);
    bool emailValidate = RegExp(
            // ignore: unnecessary_string_escapes
            "^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,253}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,253}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*")
        .hasMatch(state.user!.emailAddress!);
    if (emailValidate) {

      EasyDebounce.debounce(
          'email-address-debouncer',  
          const Duration(milliseconds: 100),  
          () async {
        response = await _userRepository.accountExist(state.user);

        switch (response?.status) {
          case 200:
            state.status = AuthenticationStatus.success;
            state.user?.isAccountExists = response?.response!.isAccountExists;

            break;
          case 500:
            state.status = AuthenticationStatus.serverError;
          default:
            state.status = AuthenticationStatus.failed;
            state.errorMessage = response?.message!;
            break;
        }
      });

      await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 0), ()  async{
       
      final newState=AccountState(user: state.user?.copyWith(
        isAccountExists: response?.response!.isAccountExists,
        emailAddress: state.user?.emailAddress,
      ));

        emit(newState);

      });
    }
  }

